# How to Fire Submit button Click Event using WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have the following HTML code and I want to fire the click event of accept submit button using WebRequest in C#

```
<form method="get" action="test">
          <input class="accept" type="submit" value="Accept">
          <input class="decline" type="button" name="decline" value="Decline">
</form>
```

Please let me know the ways t0 achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by webrequest ? 
Do you mean C# built-in object WebRequest ?!!!

Comment: Yes. Its an inbuilt object in which we can pass url and get the response

Comment: So when I pass the url of this page it will show the above content but I want the html of the page which will be displayed after clicking on Accept Button

Comment: Please provide the  complete html of what you get with webrequest then I can answer you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click "Accept", the browser will automatically send a GET request to the specified action `"test"` on the server hosting the webpage that contains the form.

```
GET http://example.com/test?
```

Here is an example to illustrate that "firing the sumbit event" has nothing to do with C#, but is a feature of html.

Let`s put your form into a simple html page and save it as form.html somewhere on your computer:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="accepted.html">
            <input class="accept" type="submit" value="Accept">
            <input class="decline" type="button" name="decline" value="Decline">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the action now goes to `"accepted.html"`. Put another html file called "accepted.html" into the same folder as form.html. When you open form.html in your browser and click "Accept", the static page accepted.html will be shown. (Here your webbrowser also acts as server for local files.)

So your question is probably not "How do I fire the click event of the submit button" but rather "How do I handle dynamic requests instead of serving static pages".

You want your webserver to intercept the request for the GET action 'test', run some C# to process it and show the results.
A good framework to do this is [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview).

Answer (score 0):

this cannot be done by webrequest since this only handles.. Web requests.
This gets request like GET/POST but cannot execute js.
if you actually want to simulate clicks/etc you can however use Webclient;

```
using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
        {
            wb.Navigate("google.com");
            if (wb.Document != null)
            {
                //get your (clickable) element, for ex. the submit button.
                var el = wb.Document.GetElementById("email");
                if (el != null)
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("element not found!");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("could not load document!");
        }
```

note that this has to be run in a STA thread.
You can also write some browser-js code to test this.

```
document.GetElementById(id).click();
```

You can run this in a console in firefox/chrome.

if you must use webrequests you need to go to the page in your browser and check the 'network' tab in the element inspector.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRu7D.png)

then locate the POST request and use that link to simulate it in code.

A good example on how to use that url to post is found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx